# How can i use curl for fetch this url

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

I am trying to get an a tag using crl from a website but it seems not working.
It's working fine with other websites but it's not working with this website:

**sbplay1.c০m**

How can i make it work?

```
<?php
//$url="https://google.com";
$url= "https://sbplay1.com";
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'viewport=1040; _flashVersion=1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json ', 'Accept: *'));   
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch); 
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(3);
$ids = $node->getAttribute("href");
echo $ids;
?>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: Don't use `@` unless you have a very, very specific reason to do so. I'm seeing at least 3 potential things going on: 1) Trying to download something from a site, 2) Trying to parse something as HTML, 3) Trying to find something in that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because the url that you're trying to reach would generate a single page application(SPA). These applications execute javascript to render the information that you are searching for on the page. The reason as to why curl does not have this information is because it is not a browser and therefore cannot execute javascript. You can use something like Selenium to browse the page after js rendering.

A popular crawler that I've used in the past to read SPA pages in PHP is Spatie.

https://github.com/spatie/crawler

You can tell spatie to crawl all pages and render them as if using a browser.

Comment: Can you give me an example with crawler. I have seen the repository. The documentation they give there is really hard to understand as I'm new in php.